# Global variable would not change

Tags: python, tkinter

I called a global boolean in the function, but it still enters the 'if' even though the condition is not true.

I've been searching around but couldn't find a similar problem.

```
from Tkinter import *
import time

jumping = False
def jump(parts, high = 25): #to fix: can jump again in middle jump
    global jumping
    jumping = True
    for t in range(high*-3, 0, 1):
        w.move(parts[0], 0, 1)
        master.update()
        time.sleep(.0083)
    jumping = False
#thats the condition, which can be entered even while "jump()" is running.
if not jumping:
    master.bind('w', lambda x: jump(penguin_parts))
```

I expected it not to allow me to press 'w' and activate "jump()" when the function is in process but it actually lets me, just like jumping is still False.

Comment: `jumping` is False at the time you conditionally call `.bind()`; once the key is bound, it remains bound.  You would need to put the conditional inside `jump()` if you want it to be evaluated each time __w__ is pressed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's nothing there to unbind the w key to the jump() function. Once it's bound, it remains bound until you unbind it.

```py
from Tkinter import *
import time

jumping = False
def jump(parts, high = 25):
    if jumping == False:
        global jumping
        jumping = True
        for t in range(high*-3, 0, 1):
            w.move(parts[0], 0, 1)
            master.update()
            time.sleep(.0083)
        jumping = False
    master.bind('w', lambda x: jump(penguin_parts))
```

Comment: `
if not jumping:
    master.bind('w', lambda x: jump(penguin_parts))
else:
    master.unbind('w')
`
tried to add that 'else' but it wont seem to work. do you got any other idea? sorry for asking such basic questions, im a little bit new at this.

Comment: Okay, so right after the "def jump()":, put the if statement.

Comment: Add the `if` statement in your `jump` function (see comment from @jasonharper).

Comment: I hate that comments can't have codeblocks and linebreaks.

Comment: it still wont work. maybe its because theres an ""master.update()" inside the function so it sets the "jumping" to false once again?

Comment: I edited my answer to show you what I think should fix your problem. Could you give that a try and tell us what happens?

Comment: `if jumping = False:` is wrong. It should be `if jumping == False:` or even better `if not jumping:`

Comment: Oh my God, you're right, I can't believe I did that

Comment: you dont seem to unbind anything.
solved it at the end by just unbinding it at the start and then just binding once again at the end of the function. thanks!

Comment: In mine, I didn't actually unbind it. And you don't technically need to, unless you want "w" to have some other functionality while jumping. I just made it so you can't jump while already jumping.